# Scripting id3 tags with id3v2 and sed

Tags: bash, sed, id3

I am trying to write a script to automatically add track and title info to an mp3 file's id3 tag.

At this point, I have sed grabbing the info from the filename and formatting it to fit the id3v2 command, but upon hitting a multi-word title, I get the error `Couldn't stat file '<second word of title>'`.  If I just echo the id3v2 command that is being run, I see the command in this format:

```
id3v2 -t Title\ Of\ Track -T 1 1_-_Title_Of_Track.mp3
```

Copy/pasting that text into the terminal executes tagging properly, but of course lacks the intended automation of scripting.  So here's what the script intending to automate the process looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

for track in *.mp3 ; do
    id3v2 $(echo ${track} | sed -e 's/^\([1-9][0-9]*\)_-_\(.*\).mp3/-t \2 -T \1/' -e 's/_/\\ /g') ${track}
done
```

Any insight as to why the title is treated as a single argument when manually typed but not when scripted?

Comment: Use quotes "$track" . Also what is the final goal you want to achieve?

Comment: The intent is to tag the mp3 files with the track number and title as parsed from the file name.  The problem should not be in the file name.  The file name itself has no spaces; it uses underscores instead.  When I parse the title from the file name, I replace the underscores with `\ ` so as to have proper words for the id3 title tag.

Comment: A wild guess of what you want:  `for f in *.mp3; do id3v2 --TIT3 "${f%.*}" "$f"; done`

Comment: @ValentinB I am not at my machine to try that out, but it does not look like what I am attempting to do.  The files are named in the pattern of `<track number>_-_Title_Of_Track.mp3`.  I am parsing both the track number and title out of the file name, and replacing the underscores with spaces for the title.  Also the title is `TIT2` rather than `TIT3`, which is the sub-title.  Anyways, it looks like your command is just lopping off the file-extension and stuffing the name minus the extension into `TIT3`.

Comment: Ok I see where you are getting:  `for f in *.mp3; do  title_only="${f%.*}"; id3v2 --TIT2 "${title_only//_/ }" "$f"; done`  Is whaht you are looking for I think.  If not we can work on it

Comment: That command still does not handle the track number.  More importantly, I am not so much just looking for a command that "gets the job done", I really want to understand why my method doesn't work.  I could have easily tagged each file by hand in less time than it took for me to write a script I thought should work.  This is mostly an excuse to improve my bash/sed skills.

Comment: Well I said in my first comment. You need to quote `"$track"` and no need for  `$(echo ${track})` there. Just use `"$track"`. Also this can / should be done without sed. E.g  `for f in *.mp3; do  title_only="${f%.*}"; remove_digit="${title_only#_*}"; id3v2 --TIT2 "${remove_digit//_/ }" "$f"; done`

Comment: Your problem stems from the order of evaluation of commands. `$()` is done first, then the result is split into words. Add `set -x` to the start and you will see output like: `id3v2 -t 'Title\' 'Of\' Track -T 1 1_-_Title_Of_Track.mp3` where you can see the backslash serves no purpose.

Comment: @meuh So that explains the 'why'.  Is there a way to tell bash not to separate the result of `$()` into words, or is there some other typical workaround?

Comment: Typically one can double-quote to avoid the split `"$()"` but this results in a single string, not 4 as you want, so you could add an `eval` at the front to get the string re-parsed, but this is very messy, and people frown on eval. If you want to stick with `sed`, then instead of a mix-and-match, make sed do the entire process of conversion of the filename into the final command, and you can then pipe the output into `sh`.  If you want to solve things with sed, get to know it thoroughly. Otherwise, use the powerful bash string editing features given above, and you won't need sed at all.

Comment: I think I've gotten the information I need.  I will try to put these comments to use when I get back to my machine and update with results.

Comment: @ValentinB I appreciate the introduction to bash's string manipulation.  In the end, I wound up using that feature to parse out the track number and title into variables and pass those as arguments to the id3v2 command.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the comments from Valentin B and mueh, I ditched `sed` for the parsing in the script and instead used bash's string manipulation.  While `sed` was good for parsing multiple data and ordering it in a single command, the command-expansion to use the result would split the output up into "words" that would be delimited by spaces even if the spaces were preceded by backslash or surrounded by quotes.

So instead of trying to construct all of the arguments to `id3v2` in a single pass with `sed`, it was broken up into parsing out the track number and title separately using bash's string manipulation.  The end result:

```
for track in *.mp3 ; do
    track_num=${track%_-_*}
    title=${track#*_} ; title=${title%.mp3} ; title=${title//_/ }
    id3v2 -t "${title}" -T ${track_num} ${track}
done
```

Thanks to mueh for explaining exactly why my approach in the question was not working, and Valentin B for introducing bash's string manipulation.